# SSRS 2008 R2 Report Data not Showing Up On Server

Tags: ssrs-2008-r2

I have an issue with an SSRS report not showing up.  Any of the other reports out there (including mine) work.  This one doesn't.  It runs locally without fail.  but when it goes onto the server, nothing shows up in the viewer. (see image)  The loading gif shows up breifly, but then it goes away.

- What are the possible reasons why this could happen?
- What are the possible ways to avoid this in the future?
- How do I fix it for *this* report?

[image]

**EDIT: I noticed at the bottom of the page, i got this error:**

> Message: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 500

Comment: Can you show the query?  It sounds like a permission issue.  Is the report running under a specific account?

Comment: basically, the query is SELECT * FROM [View Name] nothing special.

Comment: Is there anything fancy in the view?  Maybe a linked table or UDF?  How about the account running it?  Is it the same account that you used to test it?

Comment: @tgolisch I solved the issue. see the answer posted. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out.  One of the parameters had a specific dataset that wasn't matching up to the right one.  So, the report was fine - but the Parameter dataset wasn't.

It's fixed.  Thanks, for your help, @tgolisch